# Not able to hit my application site url deployed in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, docker, amazon-ec2

I SSH into the EC2 instance box and manually ran my docker containers. I see that my docker container is up and my application is also deployed into the tomcat webapps folder. I verified whether my application is started successfully or not by checking the catalina.out. But i couldn't access the application url using the public ip which is shown in the Instances tab of the EC2 management console.

Between i am not able to ping the public ip displayed in that EC2 instance as well.
I am kind of stuck in this issue. Is there any other configuration i need to do to access my site using the public ip ?

Here is my security group settings which i have used 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWwAm.jpg)

Here is my inbound settings i have configured for my security group
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwhRc.jpg)

I also added a new inbound rule to allow 8080, here is the rule which i have added

```
HTTP* (8080)     TCP (6)      8080    XX-a18dXXXX
```

Comment: Edit your question and add your security group settings.

Comment: I have updated my question with the security group which i have used

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the rules in the "Outbound" security group. These rules are blocking connections from completing.

Security groups are stateful which means that if an inbound rule is enabled, then the return port will also be enabled by default. If you connect inbound on port 80 the outbound port will NOT be 80. It will be in the range of 1024 - 65534.

You should only have one rule for Outbound.

```
All traffic     All      All    0.0.0.0/0
```

If you want to enable ping, then enable "All ICMP - IPv4" in the "Inbound" security group.

Comment: Now i am able to ping the public IP address. But i am not able to access my site url which is deployed as a docker container. When i try to access the site using the following url, curl http://172.17.0.3:8080/ , i see htmls are printed. Any suggestion on how to access my site url using the public ip ?

Comment: From the putty I can confirm that my application is working by doing curl http://172.17.0.3:8080/. I am not sure how do I use the public ip to hit my application deployed in Docker container. I am sure some configuration I am missing, but not sure what it is. Any help on this would be appreciable..

Comment: Your security group does not allow port 8080. Can you double check what your configuration should be? If you need port 8080 then add that to your security group.

Comment: I have updated the Security group to add port 8080 in the Inbound Rules. But still i am not able to access my application using the public IP.

Comment: I have one more question. When i ssh into the ECS instance and try to do an curl with the public IP with the port like this curl http://Ipaddress:8080, i should be able to see application deployed in the docker container. correct ? but i am not able to access that from the ECS instance itself.

Comment: I am able to solve this issue by adding the Custom TCP Rule with the Port range of what my company has set already.